# Book about a boy and future earth?

Tags: story-identification, books, novel, young-adult

I can't remember the title and it's killing me. It's about a boy, teenage I think and he gets slung forward in time. Old medicine woman or something, name begins with an M. Apparently the earth had suffered a nuclear war or something and she was one of the first to start this new tribe. In a part of the book he actually wakes up from what he thinks is a dream smelling like smoke and has a scratch from a wolf he just fought with one of the tribes boys. He ends up falling in love with one of the girls and is asked for a dance during a ceremony. The old woman "M" gives him his spirit animal or something. It was from about 10-11 years ago that I read this book in high school. Was wondering if it might ring a bell for someone and you guys could help me out. At the end of the book though when he does "wake up" a friend or family member actually has a baby and names her the name of the old woman in the "future" of which he dreaming about and what he thought was the past was actually a future earth

Comment: Maybe, if you check this list, you remember the name of the novel? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_nuclear_holocaust_fiction#Novels

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/156631/young-adult-book-about-a-boy-who-gets-sent-through-a-portal-to-another-worldhttps://theintercept.com/2018/11/07/the-remarkable-participation-and-efficiency-of-brazils-elections-proves-how-shameful-and-deliberate-is-the-chaos-and-suppression-in-the-u-s/

Answer (score 5):

The Transall Saga (aka Blue Light) by Gary Paulsen. If "Megaan" is the woman's name?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Transall_Saga

Scratch that, try "A Time of Darkness" (aka Rocco) by Sherryl Jordan. I was misled by the "M" :-)

"An aged healer-woman, Ayoshe, helps him fit into his new life so well that the tribe agrees to accept some of the modern improvements he is able to construct for them, and to allow him to be handfast to a young woman whom he loves. It is only when he discovers that Anshur is in his future, and Ayoshe a relation born during his own real life, that he is snapped back into his original time frame. There, he finds he has been ill, in a coma, for a long period. It is only when Rocco realizes that a nuclear holocaust must have been the catastrophe that caused the regression of society and civilization that led to Anshur, and discovers that a long-lost family member has just had a baby daughter, Ayoshe, that he understands."